# What VBA string object can you use to modify paragraph

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am looking for a string object which i can declare within Excel VBA, which I can manipulate the paragraph style. 
I know you can do this with the Range object, however I am actually building a rich text string pro grammatically, then allocating that text to the result of a function.

see here.

```
Function makestring(char As String) As String
    Dim myString As String
    myString = "hello world" & char
    myString = myString & "this is the second line"
    myString.Characters(1.11).Font.color = Red ' this line is not valid
    makestring = myString
End Function
```

Comment: And for what purpose are you doing this? I think this could be used in a cell only, so why not use `Range` object...

Comment: I have a column of formulas which are each separately configured to look through a named range to find data with certain conditions. it then builds a string (with carriage returns) -- i wanted to make each line in the string result a different color -- I dont really have a range object to manipulate... thats my issue... (unless I create a temp reference to a cell, but the fact that the formula must show different color is my problem.. thanks

Comment: As mentioned by Michal, you can only manipulate the color of the string/paragraph within a Cell, it really depends on where you want to show the paragraph you create, but probably best to create the paragraph and then change the colors when you place that paragraph into the Worksheet.

Comment: Can you post how's the input and the output you wish afteR?

Comment: The `Characters` child object of a range seems to be the closest to what you want, but as you doubtless know they can't be created independently. You *can* assign them to variables if they are created on a range. Perhaps you can have a hidden worksheet which serves as the home of range objects which function simply as hosts for character objects.

Comment: Answer below is good. Main problem with the initial approach is that a UDF can not format the cell, only return a value.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a font color to a string the way you propose in your pseudo code. The proper way to do this would be to assign the font color to a range object when you insert the string into the document.

The following line of pseudo code suggests to me, that you only want a portion of the string to be in a certain color:

```
myString.Characters(1.11).Font.color = Red ' this line is not valid
```

For example, insert the string "Red and blue" in cell A1. The following code will change the font color of the subString "Red" in the string in cell A1 to red:

```
With Range("A1").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font
    .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
End With
```

When inserting the string returned by your function, simply split it up by carriage return and then assign the appropriate font colors. The following subroutine takes as parameters the range in which your string is to be inserted and the string itself and then alternates between red and black font color for each line of text:

```
Sub ChangeLineFontColors(myString As String, rng As Range)

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, sLen As Integer
    Dim vItem As Variant

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If myString <> vbNullString Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        rng.Value = myString

        If InStr(1, myString, Chr(10)) > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(myString, Chr(10)) ' change delimiter to Chr(13) or 'vbNewline', if required
            j = 1
            For i = LBound(vItem) To UBound(vItem)
                sLen = Len(vItem(i))
                With rng.Characters(Start:=j, Length:=sLen).Font
                    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
                    Else
                        .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black
                    End If
                    j = j + sLen + 1
                End With
            Next i
        End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

End Sub
```